# Element move by Jquery scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a problem with element position moving by scroll event. The problem:
I'm scrolling up the page and append 1px to the css top value (every scroll). After this I'm scrolling page to down, and remove 1px from the css top value. I think it's will return its original position, but not. Here is my code:

```
var lastScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).scroll(function(env) {

 var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();

 if (scroll > lastScroll){
    console.log('Scroll down');
    $('#home>article').css({ 
      top: "+="+1+"px"
    });                                                 
 } else {
   console.log('Scroll up');
   $('#home>article').css({
      top: "-="+1+"px"
 });

lastScroll = scroll;

});
```

Thanks for all idea!

Comment: In case you want to develop something like this: http://everylastdrop.co.uk/, I can recommend you skrollr: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

Answer (score 1):

Hope this might help, this is something I used a while ago.
What I have been using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(window).scroll(function () {
            var ttop = $('.container').position().top;
            var hcltb = $('.container').height();
            var mtop = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (mtop > ttop) {
                if (mtop < (ttop + hcltb - 400)) {
                    $('.internal_prev').css('top', (mtop - ttop + 300));
                    $('.internal_next').css('top', (mtop - ttop + 300));
                    $('.internal_commands').css('top', (mtop - ttop + 300));
                }
            }
        });
// ]]></script>
```

This will cause the div class="container" to act as the main container.
It then will cause the internal_* classes to scroll up and down inside the div with a set internal padding of 400.

It is not perfect but here you go.

Answer (score 0):

when the scroll event fires, it is *not* guaranteed to fire once for every pixel scrolled. It might fire after you scroll 10 pixels one time and 2 pixels the next. You have to track the scrollTop delta (change) from the last call to the handler.